# How to implement GROUP_CONCAT() function in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I need to do the following query in hibernate:

```sql
SELECT pt.ID_PATOLOGIA , GROUP_CONCAT(pt.NOMBRE) 
FROM  patologias AS pt
```